# oAuth/Security best practices: Account linking with 2 mobile applications

Tags: mobile, oauth-2.0, account-linking

Context:

User wants to link accounts and allow one mobile application (app A) to use data from another system (app/system B). System B also has mobile application with logged in user.
System B also has oAuth 2 server and bunch of APIs secured by JWT tokens provided by that oAuth 2.0 service.

Currently account linking is performed using oAuth authorization code flow, and for that mobile app A has to open web browser and make the user to log in into system B oAuth service. That later on provides authorization code to the System A to be exchanged for access/refresh tokens.

Problem statement:
Want to eliminate that user log in in the browser and potentially use the fact that user is already logged in into both applications (with different accounts/credentials)

Is there a way/best practices to link accounts without making user to re-enter credentials in the web browser? Ok to deviate from the typical authorization code flow.

We can change/update both systems/apps A & B.